# ChartJS: Bar chart with horizontal axis between positive and negative dataset

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js

I would like to place the x axis label between the positive and negative datasets of a bar chart.
This is what I currently have:

[image: current chart]

And this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

I have been able to achieve moving the x axis labels by changing the position x:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    stacked: true,
    position: {
      y: 35
    }
}
```

But this still sits over the top of the bars instead of between them.

Is there some way to offset a dataset start point? So that I have a space where I can put the x axis labels?